# Fetch data of a particular column of a particular row from a table onkeyup or onchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to javascript/jquery.

I am stuck with a problem where in I want to fetch the data of a particular column of a particular row from a table which is dynamically created. I wanted to use onChange or onKeyup event. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Eg: 
**table defination**

```html
<table id="QuotaTbl">
  <th>
    <td>Value</td>
    <td>Text</td>
  </th>
  <tbody id="quota">

  </tbody>
</table>
```

dynamically adds rows & data to the tbody.

How do I fetch in which row which column data changed? Please help!

Comment: `onChange or onKeyup event` of which element?

Comment: if a user is changing some value in a column of a particular row, that value should be captured.@gurvinder372

Comment: what's your source of data ? How do you get them and save them ?

Comment: @Alexis i am fetching the data from a service and binding it through js file.

Comment: You need to create input on each row and call ajax method who save your values onkeyup.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question so you need to get the table cell where the user changed its value 
you can use something like this

```
$('table tr td').on('change',function(){
   //value
  var value = $(this).val();
})
```

Comment: Thank you @Peter but will the snippet you gave work for any column in any row. Please spare me if am asking some illogical questions.

Comment: @Karan yes it will work for any column on any row in the tale